# JQuery Click Event Problem

Tags: jquery, modalpopup

Im creating modal popup using jquery. Im firing the modal pop up through button click event and the corresponding code here

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                el = document.getElementById("overlayDiv");
                el.style.visibility = "visible";
                el1 = document.getElementById("progress");
                el1.style.visibility = "visible";
                el2 = document.getElementById("image");
                el2.style.visibility = "hidden";
            });
        });
```

This works when I click the button at first, after that it doesnt works.

Thanks,
Hari.

Comment: Two elements are shown and one hidden. Are you reversing that at some later point? If so how? If not, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: how do you hide them, once you close the modal window ?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not use the jQuery functions instead of   old-school javascript/css. show() hide() & $() are your friend.

Answer (score 2):

`visibility` and `display` (used by `.hide()`) are different.  Instead of `visibility: hidden`, in your CSS use `display: none`, then you can use jQuery's `show()`/`hide()` functionality like this:

```
$("#Button1").click(function () {
   $("#overlayDiv, #progress").show();
   $("#image").hide();
});​
```

It sounds like you're using `.hide()` to hide the modal, if that's the case, this will fix the issue.  Also, a bit less code :)

Comment: Here my click event happens only one time,my need is it should happen for successive times.

Comment: @ram Can you confirm that's the case by sticking an alert in the click?  I sounds more like it's not having an effect than it not firing.  Also, is it in an update panel, or otherwise replaced by ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $find(Your popup ID).show();
```