# Jquery click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(showDialog);
});

var showDialog = function () {
    /* Something I do here */
}
```

Here the "Button1" click event fire at first time, after that the event was not firing.

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: @ram: Please refine your question instead of repeatedly asking the same question. And consider replying to comments if the answers do not solve your problem. Exact duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528914 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529023

Answer (score 2):

Something in `showDialog` is causing an error which 'halts' the processing of further actions.

Check your browsers error log. If you're in Firefox, just press Ctrl+Shift+J and a list of errors on the page should pop up.